# Create a new column that counts the number of a sub-string in a string column?

Tags: r, dplyr, stringr

New to R here. I have a problem to solve: I need to create some new columns that count 1 if a sub-string appears one or more times in a string column. Like this:

```
Existing Column         New Col (True if apple)    New Col (True if banana)
apple, apple, orange            1                              0
banana, banana, orange          0                              1
apple, banana, orange           1                              1
```

Anyone can help me with this? Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: I tried to insert text but it came out wrong... how do I insert a table in my question?

Comment: Copy and paste, then highlight it and hit the code button. Or just indent it all by 4 spaces.

Comment: It may be useful to first take a look at how to create a df and paste its output here - for both sample input and sample output. You can use the 'braces' to format as code, which allows us all to view it in proper format.

Comment: Ahh, got it thanks! Yeah as seen in the post, I want to create those new columns.

Answer (score 3):

So I thought you wanted columns of counts (not whether strings are contained) the first time I read the question (the previous edit), but it's sort of useful code anyway, so I left it. Here are options for both base R and the `stringr` package:

First let's make a sample data.frame with similar data

```
# stringsAsFactors = FALSE would be smart here, but let's not assume...
df <- data.frame(x = c('a, b, c, a', 'b, b, c', 'd, a'))
```

which looks like

```
> df
           x
1 a, b, c, a
2    b, b, c
3       d, a
```

---

## Base R

Use `strsplit` to make a list of vectors of separated strings, using `as.character` to coerce factors to a useful form,

```
list <- strsplit(as.character(df$x), ', ')
```

then make a list of unique strings

```
lvls <- unique(unlist(list))
```

#### Making Contains Columns

Loop over the rows of the data.frame/list with `sapply`. (All `sapply` functions in this answer could be replaced with `for` loops, but that's generally considered poor style in R for speed reasons.) Test if the unique strings are in each, and change to integer format. Set the result (`t`ransposed) to a new column of `df`, one for each unique string.

```
df[, lvls] <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(z){as.integer(lvls %in% list[[z]])}))

> df
           x a b c d
1 a, b, c, a 1 1 1 0
2    b, b, c 0 1 1 0
3       d, a 1 0 0 1
```

To keep values as Boolean `TRUE`/`FALSE` instead of integers, just remove `as.integer`.

#### Making Count Columns

Loop over the rows of the data.frame/list with the outside `sapply`, while the inner one loops over the unique strings in each, and counts the occurrences by summing `TRUE` values. Set the result (`t`ransposed) to a new column of `df`, one for each unique string.

```
df[, lvls] <- t(sapply(1:nrow(df), function(z){
    sapply(seq_along(lvls), function(y){sum(lvls[y] == list[[z]])})
}))

> df
           x a b c d
1 a, b, c, a 2 1 1 0
2    b, b, c 0 2 1 0
3       d, a 1 0 0 1
```

---

## `stringr`

`stringr` can make these tasks much more straightforward.

First, find unique strings in `df$x`. Split strings with `str_split` (which can take a factor), flatten them into a vector with `unlist`, and find unique ones:

```
library(stringr)
lvls <- unique(unlist(str_split(df$x, ', ')))
```

#### Making Contains Columns

`str_detect` allows us to only loop over the unique strings, not rows:

```
df[, lvls] <- sapply(lvls, function(y){as.integer(str_detect(df$x, y))})
```

#### Making Count Columns

`str_count` simplifies our syntax dramatically, again only looping over `lvls`:

```
df[,lvls] <- sapply(lvls, function(y){str_count(df$x, y)})
```

Results for both are identical to those in base R above.

Answer (score 2):

So, without full details, it is very hard to know exactly what you are looking for. But, if you are looking for number of times a given string occurs and adding as a column to the original data, here is one approach that works (replicating your data input):

```
df <- data.frame(Fruit = c('apple,orange,orange', 'banana,banana,pear', 'apple,banana,orange'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

df$appleCount <- lapply(strsplit(df$Fruit, ','), function(x) sum('apple' == x))
df$bananaCount <- lapply(strsplit(df$Fruit, ','), function(x) sum('banana' == x))
```

This will only work when you know the specific strings you identified to add as columns. But, should give you an idea of how to split strings, count how many of a given are in that split list, etc. Hope this helps.

Output from the above code should be this:

```
                Fruit appleCount bananaCount
1 apple,orange,orange          1           0
2  banana,banana,pear          0           2
3 apple,banana,orange          1           1
```

If you are not looking for the count of times a given string occurs, but just only a true/false (0/1) of whether the string occurs or not, you can use this slightly modified code to get that result:

```
df <- data.frame(Fruit = c('apple,orange,orange', 'banana,banana,pear', 'apple,banana,orange'), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df$appleCount <- lapply(strsplit(df$Fruit, ','), function(x) 'apple' %in% x)
df$bananaCount <- lapply(strsplit(df$Fruit, ','), function(x) 'banana' %in% x)
```

The output will be then as follows:

```
            Fruit appleCount bananaCount
1 apple,orange,orange       TRUE       FALSE
2  banana,banana,pear      FALSE        TRUE
3 apple,banana,orange       TRUE        TRUE
```

If you really want 0/1, you can use `as.integer` to convert a logical column to integer value.

Comment: Up voting and/or accepting answer is how you can thank on Stackoverflow. :)

Comment: I did... but because my account is new, stack overflow won't let me do it just yet.    Follow up question: what if I want to look for both apple or banana in the string? Which means either banana or apple is in the string, I want the new column to return true.

Comment: You need to look up '|' and '&' operators to combine. For example, you can do: `sum('apple' == x | 'banana' == x)` as one possibility.

Answer (score 2):

Using "df" from @user3949008's answer, you can also try `cSplit_e` from my "splitstackshape" package:

```
library(splitstackshape)
cSplit_e(df, "Fruit", ",", type = "character", fill = 0)
#                 Fruit Fruit_apple Fruit_banana Fruit_orange Fruit_pear
# 1 apple,orange,orange           1            0            1          0
# 2  banana,banana,pear           0            1            0          1
# 3 apple,banana,orange           1            1            1          0
```

You can always drop the columns you're not interested in later.

If you're after counts, you can try `mtabulate` from "qdapTools":

```
library(qdapTools)
mtabulate(strsplit(df$Fruit, ","))
#   apple banana orange pear
# 1     1      0      2    0
# 2     0      2      0    1
# 3     1      1      1    0
```

Comment: `base::strsplit` isn't vectorized (frustratingly); you'd have to use something like `stringr::str_split` for the second. Impressive knowledge of packages, though.

Comment: @alistaire ? What do you mean that `strsplit` isn't vectorized? It is.

Comment: Wait, you're totally right (sorry!), which makes me wonder why it was raising errors for me earlier...hmm.

Comment: @alistaire, probably because you were trying to split factors. When you used `apply`, it would have converted them to characters (I presume).